# Methods for finding the Eigenvalues of a matrix using python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, eigenvalue

I am currently attempting to find the eigenvalues of a matrix H.
I have tried using both numpy.linalg.eig and scipy.linalg.eig, although both apparently use the same underlying method.

The problem is that my matrix H is purely real, and the eigenvalues have to be real  and also positive.

But the scipy and numpy methods return complex Eigenvalues, both positive and negative, which because they are complex and negative, cannot be correct.
EDIT I know that the Eigenvalues must be real as the matrix represents a physical system where a complex eigenvalue would have no meaning \end EDIT

Does anyone know of any other way that I can obtain the correct, purely real, Eigenvalues of a matrix in python?

Thank you for your time!
EDIT 3:
Corrected H matrix gives purely real eigenvalues, so my imaginary problem dissapears. Now I just need to figure out why my the Eigenvalues are too big, but that is another question!

Many Thanks to all those who responded!

Corrected H matrix is below for interest.
Notice that my problem now the eigenvalues are too large.
I expected values in the range 0-1. Not ~10^50!

CORRECTED H MATRIX EIGENVALUES:

```
[ -1.56079757e-02  -6.70247389e+59  -1.31298702e+56  -3.64404066e+52
  -9.70803701e+48  -1.85917866e+45  -1.65895844e+41  -5.61503911e+39
  -7.19768059e+36  -4.58657021e+32  -4.98763491e+28  -3.08561491e+27
  -3.63383072e+25  -2.58033979e+25  -3.45930959e+23  -2.13272853e+18
  -4.25175990e+21  -1.93387466e+22]
```

CORRECTED H MATRIX:

```
[[ -1.56079757e-02  -1.96247112e-02  -2.02799782e-02  -1.99695485e-02
   -1.93678897e-02  -1.86944625e-02  -1.30222438e+04  -3.54051869e+05
   -4.91571514e+06  -4.51159690e+07  -3.09207669e+08  -1.69913322e+09
   -2.76231241e+15  -4.29262866e+17  -3.76558847e+19  -2.27013318e+21
   -1.03308991e+23  -3.75607123e+24]
 [ -1.96247112e-02  -3.16659228e-02  -3.73018152e-02  -3.99083810e-02
   -4.09801356e-02  -4.12397330e-02  -9.25855152e+03  -2.52585509e+05
   -3.52145205e+06  -3.24749687e+07  -2.23781425e+08  -1.23712026e+09
   -1.95621015e+15  -3.04176626e+17  -2.67015928e+19  -1.61101326e+21
   -7.33788197e+22  -2.67049818e+24]
 [ -2.02799782e-02  -3.73018152e-02  -4.77923287e-02  -5.41249519e-02
   -5.79464638e-02  -6.01988341e-02  -7.57318263e+03  -2.06839231e+05
   -2.88760361e+06  -2.66717677e+07  -1.84121508e+08  -1.01989311e+09
   -1.59803489e+15  -2.48531861e+17  -2.18219073e+19  -1.31694511e+21
   -6.00020265e+22  -2.18437720e+24]
 [ -1.99695485e-02  -3.99083810e-02  -5.41249519e-02  -6.39296468e-02
   -7.06496425e-02  -7.52593492e-02  -6.56444085e+03  -1.79388958e+05
   -2.50607920e+06  -2.31660126e+07  -1.60063118e+08  -8.87505427e+08
   -1.38428190e+15  -2.15309349e+17  -1.89070134e+19  -1.14117996e+21
   -5.20014426e+22  -1.89341950e+24]
 [ -1.93678897e-02  -4.09801356e-02  -5.79464638e-02  -7.06496425e-02
   -8.00703376e-02  -8.70367786e-02  -5.87456014e+03  -1.60590211e+05
   -2.24436978e+06  -2.07565818e+07  -1.43492007e+08  -7.96094702e+08
   -1.23832305e+15  -1.92618393e+17  -1.69155984e+19  -1.02106226e+21
   -4.65319430e+22  -1.69443289e+24]
 [ -1.86944625e-02  -4.12397330e-02  -6.01988341e-02  -7.52593492e-02
   -8.70367786e-02  -9.62124393e-02  -5.36462746e+03  -1.46683176e+05
   -2.05056240e+06  -1.89701536e+07  -1.31188910e+08  -7.28124191e+08
   -1.13054072e+15  -1.75859951e+17  -1.54445848e+19  -9.32316767e+20
   -4.24900807e+22  -1.54734986e+24]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  -4.12478326e+18  -5.45644679e+19
   -2.90876009e+20  -8.98307694e+20  -1.93571800e+21  -3.25655840e+21
   -1.23009840e+30  -2.34880436e+32  -2.19696316e+34  -1.25767256e+36
   -4.92737192e+37  -1.41676103e+39]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  -5.45644679e+19  -1.18364260e+21
   -9.55137274e+21  -4.18185914e+22  -1.20837111e+23  -2.59872572e+23
   -4.88154308e+30  -1.23670123e+33  -1.52633071e+35  -1.14675488e+37
   -5.86768809e+38  -2.19383952e+40]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  -2.90876009e+20  -9.55137274e+21
   -1.10203112e+23  -6.57480361e+23  -2.48279601e+24  -6.72600978e+24
   -9.55655956e+30  -2.93055192e+33  -4.39290725e+35  -4.01427998e+37
   -2.49882367e+39  -1.13605487e+41]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  -8.98307694e+20  -4.18185914e+22
   -6.57480361e+23  -5.15935422e+24  -2.48241611e+25  -8.32646595e+25
   -1.32363927e+31  -4.60841402e+33  -7.90547208e+35  -8.31277603e+37
   -5.97680290e+39  -3.14644094e+41]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  -1.93571800e+21  -1.20837111e+23
   -2.48279601e+24  -2.48241611e+25  -1.48582210e+26  -6.06263231e+26
   -1.52615891e+31  -5.77316621e+33  -1.08616056e+36  -1.26177499e+38
   -1.00789238e+40  -5.92030497e+41]
 [  0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00  -3.25655840e+21  -2.59872572e+23
   -6.72600978e+24  -8.32646595e+25  -6.06263231e+26  -2.95791640e+27
   -1.59124215e+31  -6.34774909e+33  -1.27102306e+36  -1.58346849e+38
   -1.36500133e+40  -8.69716304e+41]
 [ -2.76231241e+15  -1.95621015e+15  -1.59803489e+15  -1.38428190e+15
   -1.23832305e+15  -1.13054072e+15   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
   -3.91170589e+42  -3.71477021e+44  -1.55100113e+46  -3.65410576e+47
   -5.53824601e+48  -5.87586247e+49]
 [ -4.29262866e+17  -3.04176626e+17  -2.48531861e+17  -2.15309349e+17
   -1.92618393e+17  -1.75859951e+17   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
   -3.71477021e+44  -5.04566596e+46  -2.92377802e+48  -9.33903419e+49
   -1.88272072e+51  -2.61414916e+52]
 [ -3.76558847e+19  -2.67015928e+19  -2.18219073e+19  -1.89070134e+19
   -1.69155984e+19  -1.54445848e+19   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
   -1.55100113e+46  -2.92377802e+48  -2.28558880e+50  -9.63567387e+51
   -2.51888438e+53  -4.46829479e+54]
 [ -2.27013318e+21  -1.61101326e+21  -1.31694511e+21  -1.14117996e+21
   -1.02106226e+21  -9.32316767e+20   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
   -3.65410576e+47  -9.33903419e+49  -9.63567387e+51  -5.25195965e+53
   -1.74576666e+55  -3.88366439e+56]
 [ -1.03308991e+23  -7.33788197e+22  -6.00020265e+22  -5.20014426e+22
   -4.65319430e+22  -4.24900807e+22   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
   -5.53824601e+48  -1.88272072e+51  -2.51888438e+53  -1.74576666e+55
   -7.26381158e+56  -1.99648815e+58]
 [ -3.75607123e+24  -2.67049818e+24  -2.18437720e+24  -1.89341950e+24
   -1.69443289e+24  -1.54734986e+24   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
   -5.87586247e+49  -2.61414916e+52  -4.46829479e+54  -3.88366439e+56
   -1.99648815e+58  -6.69651817e+59]]
```

I have left the prior incorrect H matrix so that already existing answers make sense to any future readers.

EDIT 2: 
old H matrix that is definitely not right.

```
[[  9.84292024e+03  -8.31470427e+03   1.28883548e+04  -1.42234052e+03
    6.39075781e+03   1.68134522e+03   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
   -5.93837816e+16   6.38322749e+16  -6.85843186e+16   5.75338966e+16
   -4.88603241e+16   3.50805052e+16]
 [ -8.31470427e+03   1.16557521e+05  -3.57981876e+05   7.96363898e+05
   -1.49026732e+06   2.53900589e+06   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    8.06918956e+18  -3.72079304e+19   1.23800418e+20  -3.42505937e+20
    8.36989008e+20  -1.86726751e+21]
 [  1.28883548e+04  -3.57981876e+05   3.15391321e+06  -1.63653726e+07
    6.55556033e+07  -2.25027001e+08   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
   -2.29647856e+20   2.23060743e+21  -1.47751020e+22   7.86504336e+22
   -3.61027130e+23   1.48623808e+24]
 [ -1.42234052e+03   7.96363898e+05  -1.63653726e+07   1.68187967e+08
   -1.22007429e+09   7.18684022e+09   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    3.46309077e+21  -5.84715936e+22   6.46859079e+23  -5.59189865e+24
    4.08308120e+25  -2.63166392e+26]
 [  6.39075781e+03  -1.49026732e+06   6.55556033e+07  -1.22007429e+09
    1.47164022e+10  -1.36810088e+11   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
   -3.69586675e+22   9.89735934e+23  -1.67505077e+25   2.15859810e+26
   -2.30442140e+27   2.13906412e+28]
 [  1.68134522e+03   2.53900589e+06  -2.25027001e+08   7.18684022e+09
   -1.36810088e+11   1.90724566e+12   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    3.17341100e+23  -1.27716724e+25   3.13774985e+26  -5.72503211e+27
    8.49214835e+28  -1.07936569e+30]
 [ -2.62366128e+07   3.12867102e+08  -2.07586348e+09   9.55718390e+09
   -3.58688215e+10   1.18206299e+11  -3.72545099e+19   3.55377485e+20
   -2.19797302e+21   1.06820421e+22  -4.43482421e+22   1.64613799e+23
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  6.21899934e+06  -1.35300269e+09   2.25199661e+10  -2.08147670e+11
    1.41978312e+12  -8.03720030e+12   3.55377485e+20  -6.92933885e+21
    7.86285194e+22  -6.60223225e+23   4.55617308e+24  -2.73627888e+25
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [ -2.10320449e+07   4.11734924e+09  -1.49402973e+11   2.51974540e+12
   -2.86573004e+13   2.56306446e+14  -2.19797302e+21   7.86285194e+22
   -1.49349605e+24   1.98682041e+25  -2.09455082e+26   1.87262719e+27
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [  2.94574146e+06  -1.02367345e+10   7.58502833e+11  -2.20591701e+13
    3.96780330e+14  -5.32688366e+15   1.06820421e+22  -6.60223225e+23
    1.98682041e+25  -3.97295506e+26   6.07807050e+27  -7.69005025e+28
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [ -1.34143013e+07   2.23461195e+10  -3.24369808e+12   1.56693459e+14
   -4.30207139e+15   8.37537551e+16  -4.43482421e+22   4.55617308e+24
   -2.09455082e+26   6.07807050e+27  -1.30367761e+29   2.25611610e+30
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [ -1.29818367e+06  -4.45010813e+10   1.22995908e+13  -9.61118583e+14
    3.92675368e+16  -1.08141277e+18   1.64613799e+23  -2.73627888e+25
    1.87262719e+27  -7.69005025e+28   2.25611610e+30  -5.21172115e+31
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00
    0.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
 [ -5.93837816e+16   8.06918956e+18  -2.29647856e+20   3.46309077e+21
   -3.69586675e+22   3.17341100e+23  -4.12843622e+30   1.31023908e+32
   -2.32666430e+33   2.96546578e+34  -3.03538906e+35   2.65606764e+36
   -3.91170589e+42   9.60158418e+43  -1.53011091e+45   1.88717441e+46
   -1.94862667e+47   1.76215269e+48]
 [  6.38322749e+16  -3.72079304e+19   2.23060743e+21  -5.84715936e+22
    9.89735934e+23  -1.27716724e+25   3.81005492e+31  -2.11434722e+33
    5.97475670e+34  -1.14689052e+36   1.70519806e+37  -2.11260012e+38
    9.60158418e+43  -3.55965236e+45   8.25594136e+46  -1.44373334e+48
    2.07304224e+49  -2.56816531e+50]
 [ -6.85843186e+16   1.23800418e+20  -1.47751020e+22   6.46859079e+23
   -1.67505077e+25   3.13774985e+26  -2.44128687e+32   2.26787992e+34
   -9.81982973e+35   2.73945925e+37  -5.71489855e+38   9.68877560e+39
   -1.53011091e+45   8.25594136e+46  -2.68951294e+48   6.44111112e+49
   -1.24291248e+51   2.03914940e+52]
 [  5.75338966e+16  -3.42505937e+20   7.86504336e+22  -5.59189865e+24
    2.15859810e+26  -5.72503211e+27   1.26953404e+33  -1.91719765e+35
    1.23852494e+37  -4.89510985e+38   1.39768692e+40  -3.16418412e+41
    1.88717441e+46  -1.44373334e+48   6.44111112e+49  -2.06086355e+51
    5.21505047e+52  -1.10591734e+54]
 [ -4.88603241e+16   8.36989008e+20  -3.61027130e+23   4.08308120e+25
   -2.30442140e+27   8.49214835e+28  -5.72744451e+33   1.37649297e+36
   -1.30066841e+38   7.14559647e+39  -2.74085484e+41   8.13459136e+42
   -1.94862667e+47   2.07304224e+49  -1.24291248e+51   5.21505047e+52
   -1.69908728e+54   4.57315759e+55]
 [  3.50805052e+16  -1.86726751e+21   1.48623808e+24  -2.63166392e+26
    2.13906412e+28  -1.07936569e+30   2.32655148e+34  -8.75599541e+36
    1.19185355e+39  -8.96773338e+40   4.55433688e+42  -1.74680817e+44
    1.76215269e+48  -2.56816531e+50   2.03914940e+52  -1.10591734e+54
    4.57315759e+55  -1.54023048e+57]]
```

Comment: Have you checked [numpy.linalg.eigh](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html)?

Comment: Unfortunately my matrix isn't Hermitian or symmetric.

Comment: How do you know it has real and positive eigenvalues beforehand? Please provide a code example

Comment: Without seeing H (or a smaller version of H which shows the same behaviour), it's hard to know if your matrix has numerical features which make the process of finding the eigenvalues unstable, or if the imaginary components of all the eigenvalues are negligible, or any of several other things.

Comment: My Matrix is an 18*18 Hamiltonian matrix calculated from a 7 parameter minimization problem. I have edited in the current H matrix, although until I am sure that the minimisation routine is actually working correctly I don't know if it is correct. I cannot tell if the minimisation routine is working correctly until I can obtain physically meaningful eigenvalues. A complex energy eigenvalue doesn't mean anything, so the posted H may or may not be remotely correct.

Comment: Upon inspection of the matrix (it is not in a Python-usable form), with elements ranging from `0` to `10**57`, I find it hard to believe that this matrix happens to have only positive eigenvalues. Even if it does have this property in principle, the wild range of element values suggest numerical issues both in the derivation of the matrix elements and in the subsequent process of finding eigenvalues.

Comment: Thanks @Stelios, back to square one then :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard method would be to use [numpy.linalg.eig](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html).

```
from numpy import linalg as LA
w, v = LA.eig(np.diag((1, 2, 3)))
# w:
# array([ 1.,  2.,  3.])
# v:
# array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
#        [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

Obviously, if your matrix is very specific (let's say very large and sparse), usually you want to use iterative approach (e.g. *Krylov subspace method*) to find most dominant eigenvalues. See [discussion](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/arpack.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with [libeigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org)? There's a nice Python wrapper for it, called [minieigen](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/minieigen).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import minieigen as eigen

M = eigen.Matrix3(1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3)
print(M.spectralDecomposition())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your matrix does not have any Hamiltonian structure as

```
J.dot(A).dot(J.T) - A.T
```

is not zero where `J` is given by

```
# J = [0  I]
#     [-I 0]
J = np.rot90(sp.linalg.block_diag(np.rot90(-eye(9)),np.rot90(eye(9))))
```

hence there is no condition for eigenvalues to be real and symmetric with respect to imaginary axis. Also you can scale down your matrix with the smallest number of power of ten appearing in your matrix.

Do you maybe have the extended Hamiltonian pencil in mind ?

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected my H matrix. I made some transcription based mistakes in calculating the matrix.

I'm afraid I do not know what a Hamiltonian pencil is.